# How to save the design of an Access database -- not the content -- as text?

Tags: database-design, ms-access-2010, ms-access-2007

How can I save the *entire* design or specifications of an Access 2007 database -- not the data *content* -- as text?

I have fallen foul of the "Enter Parameter Value" bug whereby a query pop-up shows an out-of-date query name -- despite having the Name AutoCorrect Options turned on *and* having run Compact and Repair Database.

I have read that Name AutoCorrection is buggy.
I've also read that it was possible to save an object as text (in an earlier version of Access) and think this would be a valuable means of making name changes everywhere -- queries and forms as well as tables.

<sub>Please do not try to convince me not to change names; that may only make me more determined to do so ;-)</sub>

Comment: I don't believe it's a native function at all, but this [SE question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/172895/table-creation-ddl-from-microsoft-access) may be helpful.

Comment: @JohnM - Thanks but, not really useful. I edited the Q a little to indicate it's not just the table design i'm wanting to fiddle with.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In [This Blog Post](https://adinuryanto.wordpress.com/2012/01/05/how-to-export-table-structure-of-ms-access-database/), Adi Nuryanto gives a great process by which you can accomplish this via a "legacy operation", which I have reproduced below:

> 1.Open MS Access and open your database. (For this sample the CarsDB.MDB sample database installed with ASPxperience was used)
>
> 2.Press ALT+T+Y+D to open the Documentor. (This is a legacy menu option that still works as long as you know the shortcut)
>
> 3.Click the Table tabs
>
> 4.In the Documentor Table tab check the Cars and CarScheduling tables (see Figure 1)
>
> 5.Click the Options button
>
> 6.In the Include for Table group check Properties only
>
> 7.In the Include for Fields group select the Names, Data Types, and Sizes radio button
>
> 8.In the Include for Indexes group select the Nothing radio button (see Figure 2).
>
> 9.Click OK to close the Print Table Definition dialog
>
> 10.Click OK to generate the documentation
>
> 11.When the documentation report is finished the Print Preview tab will be displayed. Click Text File in the Data section to export the
>   report to a text file
>
> 12.In the Export – Text File dialog (see Figure 3)
>
> 13.Check open the destination file after the export operation is complete
>
> 14.Click OK
>
> 15.For the encoding choose Windows default

An alternative to the above keyboard shortcut: 
    **Database Tools** | Analyze | **Database Documenter**

Comment: After repeating the procedure, substituting Queries (for Tables) at step 3, i found *exactly* where the problems were, and even managed to fix them within Access!